# Openshift 3 FREE- custom domain

Tags: dns, openshift, openshift-3

I am trying to migrate my app from Openshift 2 FREE to Openshift 3 FREE. I've managed to do everything, but the custom domain. In OpenShift it was very easy - add an alias to the app + modify some CNAME records in your domain. Now I do not find it easy.

Could anyone elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenShift Online Starter does not support you being able to use a custom domain. Only OpenShift Online Pro support customs domains at this point in time.

The only way to have a custom domain with OpenShift Online Starter, is to use Cloudflare or other service which can act as a proxy in front and which accepts requests for your custom domain name and forwards on requests onto OpenShift at the generated hostname given you.

Comment: Great to know, so it is not possible. Not possible not cause of the concept, but cause of the money (PRO support that still, yes?). So under the cover of migrating to the new platform - OpenShift Company gives 1 month to death for developers + at the end of this path want money! Ha Ha! PS. Thanks for givin -2 for my question - really - thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the crisp answer. Can you please help me with Cloudflare configurations settings too??